# SCSS, BEM: Difficult to find className in IDE

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I'm using scss with BEM convention in my project.
As project scales larger, I feel that it becomes difficult to maintain.

For example,

```
.card {
  &__title {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```
<div class="card__title">
TITLE_OF_THIS_CARD
</div>
```

In this situation, if I want to change the style of the card title, I think I will usually try to search for the text ".card__title" in IDE.
But, actually, it seems that it should not be searched as ".card__title", but as ".card { &_title".

If project is small, it won't be a problem, but project scales more larger, I feel that these things cause difficulties in maintenance.

Is there any way or tip for this situation?

Comment: seperate components in their own files. card.scss and so on

Comment: You can just write the full class name out in your source code. Yes, it's a bit more verbose, but it's what I do in my own projects where I also use SCSS and BEM and I've personally never found it that unwieldy. The reason I've avoided concatenating strings in SCSS to create selectors is exactly the issue you've run into, where you can't search your codebase for a CSS class.

Comment: @Sysix I've already done what you suggest, but the codebase is too large to find  class name.